# Get pandas row index by clicking on treeview

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to get the row index of a dataframe (sourced by an excel spreadsheet) by clicking in the row of a treeview.

```
def OnDoubleClick(event): #use this to fill the row values by index and column
    browe.set(billing_tree.identify_row(event.y)) 
    print(browe.get())
```

browe is an IntVar

The above function returns:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uncsb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 592, in get
    return self._tk.getint(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "I001"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uncsb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\uncsb\OneDrive\Documents\Python\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py", line 9893, in OnDoubleClick
    print(browe.get())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\uncsb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 594, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "I001"
```

I printed the dataframe and the indices are numeric, as they're supposed to be, so I don't understand what's being returned.

Comment: `identify_row()` returns the *item ID*, not index.  Use `billing_tree.index()` to get the index of a *item ID*.

Comment: First, thank you. Second, I clicked on the current 2 filtered items in the tree and it returns `_tkinter.TclError: Item 39 not found` and `_tkinter.TclError: Item 54 not found`. What would be causing them to not be found and why are the indices not being shown?

Comment: Looks like you have passed `event.y` to `billing_tree.index()`.  Read carefully my past comment *"Use `billing_tree.index()` to get the index of a __item ID__"*.  So use `billing_tree.index(billing_tree.identify_row(event.y))` instead.  Suggest you to study the document on [`ttk.Treeveiw`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize how literally you meant that. I'm very much a novice, so I'm extremely grateful for the help you've given me. I bookmarked that document.